# Which formula extracts the domain name from an email address (bob@example.com -> example.com)?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, regex

Which Google Spreadsheets formula do I use to get the domain part from an email address?

Example: `bob@example.com` → `example.com`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use the following formula to obtain an URL.

### Formula

```
=IF(ISEMAIL(A2),
   REGEXEXTRACT(A2,"@(.+)"),
   IF(ISURL(A2),
     A2,
     IF(ISURL(REGEXEXTRACT(A2,"@(.+)")),
       REGEXEXTRACT(A2,"@(.+)"),
       "No valid entry"
     )
   )
 )

 Copy / Paste 
 =IF(ISEMAIL(A2),REGEXEXTRACT(A2,"@(.+)"),IF(ISURL(A2),A2,IF(ISURL(REGEXEXTRACT(A2,"@(.+)")),REGEXEXTRACT(A2,"@(.+)"),"No valid entry")))
```

### Explained

`A1` is validated for being an e-mail address. If `TRUE`, then use the `REGEXEXTRACT` formula you constructed. If the e-mail address turns out to be not a valid address, then validate for an URL. If the URL turns out to be not a valid URL, then check if the `REGEX` is an valid URL. Show text *No valid entry* is no of the `IF` statements are true.

### Screenshot

[image]

### Example

I've created an example file for you: **[Get domain from email address](https://docs.google.com/a/familietuinstra.nl/spreadsheets/d/1lfa2nBz7lIFdxresEr6o8RqsG0v6sgZw3I3_8aydJ5M/edit?usp=sharing)**

Comment: If you want both (or don't mind having both), `=split(A2, "@")` in A3 would put `bob` in A3 and `example.com` in A4. A little more concise.

Answer (score 10):

This formula will do the job:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "@(.*)")
```

If no `@` is found, the original value is shown.

The `=regexextract` function ([documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244)) executes the [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) parameter (`@(.*)`) against the value of cell `A1`, and returns the matching group.

Comment: I'm not an expert on REGEX (@Vidar is....), but the `(.*)` is too generic. Btw, if no match is found, it will throw an error.

Comment: Why is `(.*)` too generic? Don't you want everything after the `@`?

Comment: @Trengot I was thinking of something in line of `"@([A-Za-z0-9-.]+)")`

Comment: @Trengot See http://stackoverflow.com/a/7111947/1536038

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra That regex won't work with all domain names, only ASCII ones. Domain names can have Unicode characters in them, e.g. http://㯙㯜㯙㯟.net/

Comment: @BrianMarshall As I said, I'm not an expert at regex.

Comment: If no "@" is found, this formula will return `#N/A` instead of the original value. If you want to return the original value, then use this formula: `=IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "@(.*)"), A1)`

Answer (score 5):

If your email address (bob@example.com) is in A1

`=index(split(A1,"@"),0,2)` = example.com

`=index(split(A1,"@"),0,1)` = bob

You are splitting on the @ and than using index to select which column you want from the split.